# Who exactly are the people in Mal Zeth?

Tags: the-belgariad, the-malloreon

So in *The Belgariad*, we are told that the Angaraks consist of 5 tribes: Nadraks, Thulls, Murgos, Grolims and Malloreans.

However in *The Malloreon* we learn that Mallorea consists of 4 races: Karands, Melcene, Dalls and Angaraks.

So who exactly are the people living in Mal Zeth - i.e. the north west of boundless Mallorea?

Or is this just a disconnect by the author when writing the second pentalogy?

Comment: I think Grolims are not a race/tribe but priests, although it's been a while since I read the books, so I could be wrong.

Comment: Yep - https://davideddings.fandom.com/wiki/Grolim -

Comment: also - https://davideddings.fandom.com/wiki/Mal_Zeth

Answer (score 3):

After the Cracking of the World, things were in disarray in Mallorea. The Angarak military took over and the Grolims went off to found their own city of Mal Yaska. The remainder of the Malloreans founded the city of Mal Zeth.

So back then, the people living in Mal Zeth were Mallorean Angaraks. Over time, there was interbreeding with Melcenes and Karands, the by the time of the novels the average Mallorean is mixed race.